# Several sites shares the token

Tags: javascript, web, token

I have two independent sites, the ip and domain all are different.

but everyone has the token mechanism, every site login will return a token, then fetch APIs will take this token.

but there is a question, now I want the two sites token can use in each other. I mean, if I login the first site, there return a `token`, then the `token` can be use in the second site for fetch APIs.

I have this requirement, that's siteB access the siteA's APIs. user can login siteB, there gets the `tokenB`.

---

I have a idea, but I don't know whether is feasible. in the siteA, gives APIs for siteB, if the siteB access the siteA's APIs, there should take tokenB, and siteA send tokenB to siteB for verification, if is true then returns the response data.

Comment: You are looking for asymmetric cryptography then. Let both servers share a private key, which they use to sign login data (username) and a timestanp to prevent replication,

Comment: You should look into **JWT** https://jwt.io/introduction/